# MapPointSeries not calling heatRules in amcharts5?

Tags: javascript, amcharts5

I have successfully created MapPolygonSeries on amcharts5 with heatRules. But I am trying to add MapPointSeries to set the colour of the bullets. It appears to me that the heatRules are not called at all. Does anyone have a working example, or is the issue with my code obvious?

```
            var rootElements = am5.registry.rootElements;
            var root = (rootElements.length > 0? rootElements[0]: am5.Root.new("chartdiv"));
            root.container.children.clear();
            
            var chart = root.container.children.push (
                am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
                    projection: am5map.geoMercator(),
                    panX: "none",
                    panY: "none",
                    wheelX: "none",
                    wheelY: "none"
                })
            );
            
            var pointSeries = chart.series.push(
                am5map.MapPointSeries.new(root, {
                    latitudeField: "lat",
                    longitudeField: "lon",
                    fill: am5.color(0xff0000)
                })
            );

            var circleTemplate = am5.Template.new({});
            pointSeries.bullets.push(function() {
                var bulletCircle = am5.Circle.new(root, {
                    radius: 5,  
                    fill: pointSeries.get("fill"),
                    fillOpacity: 0.8
                }, circleTemplate);
                return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                    sprite: bulletCircle
                });
            });
            
            pointSeries.set("heatRules", [{
                target: circleTemplate,
                dataField: "value",
                key: "fill"
                min: am5.color(0xff3300),
                max: am5.color(0xffff00),
            }]);

            pointSeries.data.setAll(myPointData);
```

myPointData looks like this:

```
[
{lat: -15.4183, lon: 28.287, value: 1.00448108131708},
{lat: -9.7915, lon: 29.0791, value: 1.0057251847281312},
...
]
```

Notes:

- If I do not set fill in MapPointSeries.new, then nothing is drawn (or so it appears)
- No errors in the browser console (Chrome)

Thank you in advance for any insight on this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did a workaround, but it is ugly, since I basically wrote my own heatmap function. I am still open to suggestions how to get the heatRules to work properly for points!

```
    function manualHeatMap(series) {
        if (series.length < 1) {
            return series;
        }
        var min, max;
        min = max = series[0].value;
        for (var i = 1; i < series.length; ++i) {
            if (series[i].value > max) {
                max = series[i].value;
            }
            if (series[i].value < min) {
                min = series[i].value;
            }
        }
        if (min == max) {
            min = 0;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; ++i) {
            series[i].settings = {fill: am5.color(heatRuleCalc(min, max, series[i].value))};
        }
        return series;
    }

/* ... */

            var circleTemplate = am5.Template.new({});
            pointSeries.bullets.push(function() {
                var bulletCircle = am5.Circle.new(root, {
                    radius: 7,  
                    templateField: "settings",
                    fillOpacity: 0.8
                }, circleTemplate);
                return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                    sprite: bulletCircle
                });
            });

            pointSeries.data.setAll(manualHeatMap(myPointData));
```